# Import CoreUI icons into Vue.js TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, icons, core-ui

I'm building a Vue.js app with CoreUI in TypeScript.
The problem I currently have is related to CoreUI's icons. My application runs fine and renders the icons, but VSC complains about the specific line:

```
icons: { cilHome, cilSettings },
```

Here is the entire code of my main.ts:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import CoreuiVue from "@coreui/vue";
import { cilPencil, cilSettings } from "@coreui/icons";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(CoreuiVue);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  icons: { cilPencil, cilSettings },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

VSC error text:

> No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps | undefined): CombinedVueInstance>', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store; icons: { cilHome: string[]; cilSettings: string[]; }; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'icons' does not exist in type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps'.
>     Overload 2 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps | undefined): CombinedVueInstance>', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store; icons: { cilHome: string[]; cilSettings: string[]; }; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'icons' does not exist in type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps'.
>     Overload 3 of 3, '(options?: ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition>, Record<...>> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store; icons: { cilHome: string[]; cilSettings: string[]; }; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition>, Record<...>>'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'icons' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition>, Record<...>>'.ts(2769)
>   Peek Problem
>   No quick fixes available

I assume it's a TypeScript type issue, since the code is built with no issues in EcmaScript: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template. 
I would really appreciate if you could share your experience with such issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error, by creating a custom type file xxx.d.ts:

```
import Vue, { ComponentOptions } from "vue";

declare module "vue/types/options" {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    icons?: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you create it and how did you import it ?

Comment: @LakShan, I created a folder 'custom-types' in 'src' and dropped this file into there. TypeScript picks it up automatically with no issues. So, no import needed.